# Участь разделить

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно: "разделить участь своего мужа" или "разделить участь со своим мужем"?

Answer (score 1):

Тут говорится о разных вещах. Значение разное! Например, если сказать: "разделить участь своего мужа", то тут имеется ввиду "участь мужа". Ну, а если "разделить участь со своим мужем", то тут уже больше подразумевается своя участь, которую ты хотела бы разделить с мужем.

Comment: Спасибо, Саида!